# jQuery selector by ID not accessing div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following snippet:

code:

```
<a href="" ng-click="loadNewsArticle(article.id);" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(titleList[article.id])"></a><br/><br/>
<div class="ma_shell"><div class="mobile_article" id="article{{article.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.article)"></div></div>
```

generated html:

```
<a class="ng-binding" href="" ng-click="loadNewsArticle(article.id);" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(titleList[article.id])">Article Title</a><br><br>
<div class="ma_shell"><div class="mobile_article ng-binding" id="article3" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.article)"><p>Article Content.</p></div></div>
```

jQuery in Controller:

```
$scope.loadNewsArticle = function(idno){
        $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
        $('.news-article').html("<h3>" + $scope.titleList[idno] + "</h3>" + $scope.articleList[idno]);

//      $('.mobile_article').css('display', 'block');
        $("#article3").css('display', 'block');
        return false;
};
```

The line (currently commented out) of `$('.mobile_article')` works perfectly, as expected. I originally had the next line reading `$('#article' + idno)` but hardcoded one id for testing. It doesn't work.

I basically want to do the following any time the link is clicked:
1) hide all divs of class `mobile_article`. They're hidden by default, but if one was opened by a previous link, I want it closed. 
2) show the one article associated with the link just clicked.

I literally just did this recently with a different site, but I can't access that code anymore to compare. But I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery dom manipulation with Angular?  Why don't you just use the built in ng-show directive to conditionally hide/show the elements?

Comment: I was doing it since I was already going into the function to do other work based on the click, so I figured I'd deal with the show/hide of the div while I'm in there. But that's a thought. But this is one of any number of link/content pairs generated. How would I target the ng-show?

Comment: Wait, I think I just figured it out. Let me try.

Comment: Nope. I just tried changing the code to: `      <a href="" ng-click="showID = article.id; loadNewsArticle(article.id);" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(titleList[article.id])"></a><br/><br/>
      <div class="ma_shell"><div class="mobile_article" id="article{{article.id}}" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.article)" ng-show="showID=article.id"></div></div>` and it didn't work.

Comment: If you could create a jsfiddle, that would be great.

Comment: to recreate this exact setup would be a LOAD of code. I don't know that I can get it all into a fiddle.